# Is there a way that command prompt could run a python file from Visual Code Studio?

Tags: python, cmd

I was wondering if there is a way the command prompt could run a python file when I click the run button on visual code studio. Is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can just type`python`(or py depending on your versoin of python). `python file.py` and that will run it. Then when you want to run it again, just hit the up arrow and the last command you did will be inserted and you can just hit enter and run again. Make sure you save before each run. Ctr-S to save :).

Answer (score 0):

All you do is enter this into command prompt: `PATH OF FILE`. For example, if my file was `hello.py` in Documents, then I would type in `C:/Documents/hello.py`

Comment: I think the OP was looking for a little more than just "How do I run a python program from a command prompt?"

Comment: Oh. Well that's my interpretation of the question, so sorry if its wrong

Comment: The question could have been worded better.  I think the combination of "command prompt" and "click the run button" seem to be two separate approaches.  There's an answer that uses a hotkey, which is yet a third.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible (in fact, a lot of developers and learners do this) and it can be done by following these steps:-

> 1. Download and install Python on your system and add the bin folder to the path, environment variables. (Make sure to check the ADD PATH TO ENVIRONMENT option during the installation wizard)
> 2. Install Code Runner Extension from Extension tab in VSCode
> 3. Set the configuration of terminal in VSCode to Python
> 4. Ctrl+Shift+N is the hotkey to run the Python program in terminal in VSCode.

Following all the above steps, you will see the output in the terminal.
[image: Output will be shown in the terminal]

Comment: Thanks! but How do I set the configuration to python?

Comment: It will automatically get detected once you save the file as .py